# Script to display swap utilisation in top command

Tags: swap, top

I need to write the script for displaying swap utilisation in top command, I am able to display top command but next shift+f needed to be included in script can you guys help me here

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the swap-usage for a script, I would use free.

```
# free -m
###
# free -m|grep Swap|awk '{print $3}'
```

The first command list memory and swap usage in MB. The second command gives you the used swap also in MB.

Comment: `grep Swap|awk '{print $3}'` is better written as `awk '/Swap/ { print $3 }'`.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what the question author was looking for, based on their reaction to this answer; but `top`’s swap display, as accessed through Shift-F and adding the “SWAP” column, shows per-process swap information, not the overall swap use (which is accessible directly at the top of the `top` display).